# How to make all output in a one line using html?

Tags: html, css, forms

```
<html>
<body>     
<form name="orderform" action="order.php" method="POST">
<label>Username</label><br>
<input name="user" type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="22">
<br>
<label>Items</label>
<div align="left">
 <select name="mydropdown">
<option value="macbook">Macbook</option>
<option value="sony">Sony</option>
<option value="micromax">Micromax</option>
<option value="napolean">Napolean</option>
<option value="motorola">Motorola</option>
</select>
</div>
 <label>Quantity</label>
 <div align="left">
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="quantity1">1</option>
<option value="quantity2">2</option>
<option value="quantity3">3</option>
<option value="quantity4">4</option>
<option value="quantity5">5</option>
</select>
</div>
 <input name="Order" type="submit" value="Order">
</form>
<form name="orderform" action="addtocart.php" method="POST">
    <input name="Cart" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form> 
</body>
 </html>
```

after executing this code all output is in vertical form i just wanted to make it in a line.please give me a solution i am new in php.

Comment: Are you sure it's a PHP issue ? Have a look with HTML5 / CSS3.

Comment: sorry its a html issue?

Comment: if you remove the divs it will display the controls horizontally

Comment: then my alignment will not work properly

Comment: You can optionally place your controls in a table, in individual columns in a single row. That should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
form div {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>     
    <form name="orderform" action="order.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input name="user" type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="22">
        </div>

        <div align="left">
            <label>Items</label>
            <select name="mydropdown">
                <option value="macbook">Macbook</option>
                <option value="sony">Sony</option>
                <option value="micromax">Micromax</option>
                <option value="napolean">Napolean</option>
                <option value="motorola">Motorola</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div align="left">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <select name="mydropdown">
                <option value="quantity1">1</option>
                <option value="quantity2">2</option>
                <option value="quantity3">3</option>
                <option value="quantity4">4</option>
                <option value="quantity5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="Order" type="submit" value="Order">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="Cart" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to put it all on one line using CSS. You would just remove the default line breaking effects of some elements:

```
form, form div { display: inline }
form br { display: none }
```

To do the same in HTML requires modification of the HTML markup, of course. You just remove the `div` and `br` tags, but the forms require special treatment: the way to put two forms on one line in HTML is to put them in a table:

```
<html>
<body>  
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td>   
<form name="orderform" action="order.php" method="POST">
<label>Username</label>
<input name="user" type="text" value="" size="10" maxlength="22">
<label>Items</label>
 <select name="mydropdown">
<option value="macbook">Macbook</option>
<option value="sony">Sony</option>
<option value="micromax">Micromax</option>
<option value="napolean">Napolean</option>
<option value="motorola">Motorola</option>
</select>
 <label>Quantity</label>
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="quantity1">1</option>
<option value="quantity2">2</option>
<option value="quantity3">3</option>
<option value="quantity4">4</option>
<option value="quantity5">5</option>
</select>
 <input name="Order" type="submit" value="Order">
</form>
<td>
<form name="orderform" action="addtocart.php" method="POST">
    <input name="Cart" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</form> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```